# Automatically share photos

Tags: icloud, backup, photos

I'm looking for a way that my wife and I automatically have access to each others' photos and videos. My understanding is that iCloud can't do this, and you have to manually share or add to a shared album.

Right now we're using Google Photos as an alternative - just set Google Photos to use partner sharing, and turn on automatic backup. However, Google Photos is getting ready to end unlimited storage, and I'd rather not pay for their space since I'm already paying for iCloud. And I don't think I can just delete old stuff from Google since auto-backup will just pick it up again.

Has anyone come up with another alternate strategy?

Comment: Have you looked at the “For You” section in photos lately, it’s a snap to share moments mutually. Once you set up a shared group, and enable Siri suggestions, photos learns you like to share and offers easy grouping of photos by location or day to dump into your pooled album.

Answer (score -1):

Well, as you mentioned, there is no official or easy way to do this.
The only thing I can think of is to create a "Shared Album" (Go to the album tab in the photos app and click the "+" icon, then tap the three dots in the upper left and click "Share Album"). The only thing is you will manually have to add photos to that album (Which is easy to do, just go to the "Library" view and tap "Select", select the photos, and then tap the share icon and "Add to Album").

Hope this is helpful!